# Can't read my environment variable in my Node.js app

Tags: bash, node.js, ubuntu, terminal, environment-variables

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm just learning about environment variables. I am trying to read a custom variable from within my application but it always shows up as `undefined`. Here is the code of my test app:

```
// app.js

console.log('Value: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

If I run the following commands you will see that the variable has a value:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production
$ echo $NODE_ENV
production
```

I can `echo $NODE_ENV` all day and it will continue to show me "production", but when I do `process.env.NODE_ENV` in my Node application it always displays "undefined".

```
$ node app.js
Value: undefined
```

Here is the odd part though, if I display another environment variable that I know already exists, say `process.env.PATH`, then it works.

```
$ node app.js
Value: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Another quirk is that the command `printenv list` doesn't appear to contain my custom variable `NODE_ENV` despite the fact that `echo $NODE_ENV` shows me the correct value. `printenv NODE_ENV` shows nothing as well, but `printenv PATH` shows the proper value just as it did when I accessed `PATH` in my node application.

Comment: [Read environment variables in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4870328/608639)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to `export` shell variables in order to make them available to processes you execute in your shell.

Compare the output of this command:

```
FOO=bar; bash -c 'echo $FOO'
```

with the output of this:

```
export FOO=bar; bash -c 'echo $FOO'
```

Comment: The strange this is that even if I can see variable value using `echo $FOO` I can't see it using `process.env.FOO` anyway...

Answer (score 17):

I found my way here from something really silly.

I had just added the new exported variables, but my node process still wasn't seeing them. Then I realized it wasn't enough to restart the node process—I had to open a new terminal (ie. bash instance) too. Once I did this, it worked fine :)

Comment: Thank you, it's working! I got really frustrated why it was 'undefined', all I had to do was exit bash instance and open a new one.

Comment: how do you do that? aren't these variables just set in the current shell instance? if you close the current shell and open a new one, wouldn't these variables be lost anyway?

Comment: In my case, I even had to restart Visual Studio Code. Killing and restarting the integrated terminal wasn't enough

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `dotenv` make sure to configure before you access the variables in your environment. The order of your code is mattered in js.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a library for managing app configuration.

For example **nconf** helps manage configuration through

- command line argumets
- environment variables
- files
- etc..

And looking at the source is a nice way to learn https://github.com/flatiron/nconf

Answer (score 0):

Found my way here from something really silly as well ! I was running my server file from a "src" folder inside my main project directory and so had my .env inside the "src" folder itself (from where my server was running). Once I put the .env in my main project directory, it worked for me. Make sure that your '.env' is in the main directory and not inside "src" folder.

Answer (score -2):

Restart your bash (source ~/.bashrc). This will take into account your system environment.