# How to access shell variable value from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, linux, gulp

Let's say there is a variable `key1` and its value is `123`

```
key1=123
```

so when I run the command in linux environment `echo $key1`, I get output as `123`.

[image]

Now I have the following gulp task.

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
....
gulp.task('printKeyValue', function() {
    var value1 = child_process.execSync('echo $key1');
    console.log(value1.toString().trim());
});
```

Here, I'm trying to access value of linux variable from nodejs by using [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

But when I run the following gulp task, I don't get the desired output.

```
npm run gulp -- printKeyValue
```

Instead I get output as `$key1` and not `123`.

See below screenshot

[image]

Other commands like `ls` & `pwd` in gulp task gives the desired output.

**Can some one please help on this or suggest an alternate way?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read environment variables in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/read-environment-variables-in-node-js)

Comment: Actually not sure if duplicate. Do you want to access an environment variable in Node.js like your title says, or in a subprocess command line like your code says?

Comment: @Amadan Thank you for redirecting me to an alternate solution. After looking the solution, I tried `console.log(process.env.key1);` I get the output as `undefined` which is not the expected output.

Comment: [Can't read my environment variable in my Node.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10803653/608639), [Read environment variables in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4870328/608639)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't read my environment variable in my Node.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803653/cant-read-my-environment-variable-in-my-node-js-app)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not exporting the variable. When you just do

```
key1=123
```

the variable is not propagated to subprocesses. It will be available in your current `bash` process, so you can see it when you type `echo $key1`, but it will not get inherited by the `node` process. As `man bash` says:

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that consists of the following.  Unless otherwise noted, the values are inherited from the shell.
>
> - [...]
> - shell variables and functions marked for export, along with variables exported for the command, passed in the environment

You need to either define the variable as exported

```
export key1=123
```

or mark an existing variable for export

```
key1=123
export key1
```

or launch your node with the modified environment, either via the bash innate capability to do so

```
key1=123 node code.js
```

or using `/usr/bin/env` utility:

```
env key1=123 node code.js
```

Once the variable is properly passed to the node process, it will be available both in `process.env.key1` and as `$key1` in a child process.

EDIT: I just noticed, you actually gave the command you're running; it does not matter, the same logic goes for every executable, whether `node` or `npm` or anything else.