# Linux command line Nodejs

Tags: linux, node.js

I see some NodeJS programs executed like this  PARAM=1;node program.js
Im assuming its putting PARAM=1 into the environment.  How do I access this in the node program?  thanks,

Comment: You didn't search, did you ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `PARAM=1` is setting an environment variable.

Depending on which shell you're using, you may need to use `export PARAM=1` so the setting makes it to the child process. Otherwise the value would only exist for the shell.

As dystroy pointed out, the rest of your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js).