# Is there a system for Node.js projects to automatically populate ENV?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, env

I like using `.env` -files in my projects and love that `foreman` automatically includes those values into my `ENV`.

Is there something similar for [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)?

I really don't want a plugin that needs extra configuration besides installing it, but I'd love any proper way of achieving this.

Comment: Can you just use environment variables in your Node projects?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js

Comment: @JohnZwinck That's really nasty when coordinating the project with multiple members and it's way better to project specific settings and not populate your ENV with useless crap

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are getting at here.  I'm not familiar with foreman but I supposed since you talked about "ENV" and "env" that you meant environment variables.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have sensitive values that I need for my application, like API keys, passwords, usernames etc. In a rails project I'd save these in an `.env` file which foreman parses and adds to ENV so that my app can access them.

Comment: So in Rails you are OK with passing the data via environment variables (which as far as I can tell is exactly what .env files do in foreman) but in NodeJS you are not OK with it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck No, you misunderstand me. I don't want to manually alter ENV, but automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have finally found the right plugin and it's [dotenv](https://github.com/scottmotte/dotenv/)

Answer (score 0):

`pm2` can do this, if you specify environment in .json config files (see [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/305#issuecomment-35818618) as an example)

Comment: `pm2` looks like a lot of unnecessary features for me since it's a loadbalancer etc.

Comment: it is not loadbalancer, load balancing is a node.js core feature (see [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) docs)