# Node.js: Switch npm script based on context

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is there a way to configure package.json to run a different `npm start` script based on context?  For example, I would like to run `DEBUG=http nodemon app.js` when I am developing.  But, I would like to run `node app.js` on production.

Comment: Create a bash script? After all you're just writing bash. Or create two different start actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file (e.g. server.js) and insert your app.js content.

Use this code sample inside of app.js

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }


var isDev = // Check if on dev machine

if(isDev){
  exec("DEBUG=http nodemon server.js", puts);
} else {
  exec("node server.js", puts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to also add that with express, the default environment mode is "development".  This can be changed via `app.set('env', 'production');`

Comment: Do it in your server.js via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js

You should set env variables on your system and check it in your programm.