# How to change nodepath in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

How do I view the current node_path? Is this in a configuration file?

The command `node NODE_PATH` causes error "Cannot find module".

Comment: What "path" are you trying to find?  The path where your node executable is installed? The path where NPM will install global modules to?  The path where NPM will install local modules?  The path where node will look for modules? Your current directory?

Comment: [`NODE_PATH`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) is an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). These are generally configured within the operating system. See "[How to read environment variable in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js)" for how to access them in a script.

Comment: You can view the value of `NODE_PATH` by typing `echo $NODE_PATH` on the command line.