# setup grunt with jenkins to scp depending upon the environment value i select in jenkins

Tags: deployment, jenkins, gruntjs, production

i have a project in grunt and can scp to different servers and copy stuff with `grunt scp` but every time when i have to scp to either test or production i have to change the host name in `gruntfile.js` and then commit it back to `svn` in order to run it via jenkins.So what i want is to create some environment varible on the basis of which my i can add some parameters in jenkins and when i select any of the parameter e.g. `test` by build will get deploy to test and so on. my scp code is below

```
scp: {
      options: {
        host: 'testserver',
        username: 'user',
        privateKey: fs.readFileSync('/repository/server/.ssh/id_rsa_robot'),
        tryKeyboard: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          cwd: './dist',
          src: '**/*',
          filter: 'isFile',
           // path on the server
          dest: '/path/to/deploy/project.test'
        }]  
      }
     }
```

i want to use something like

```
grunt deploy:test
```

or

```
   grunt deploy:production
```

and ask `jenkins` to do that scp

please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used Grunt, but any parameter that you configure in Jenkins under *"This build is parameterized"* section is available as environment variables for the processes under that build (with the same name as configured)

According to this answer, [Read environment variables in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js?rq=1), to read an environment variable in nodejs (and I understand that Grunt uses nodejs), all you need is:
`process.env.ENV_VARIABLE`
Where `ENV_VARIABLE` is the name of the environment variable, as configured in Jenkins.

So, in your case:

- Check mark "This build is parameterized" in Jenkins job config.
- Add "Choice" parameter type.
- Give it a name, like `Hostname`
- Provide a list of possible values
- In your file, use:
  `host: process.env.Hostname,`

Answer (score 1):

Other options is to create a json file from where you collect environments variables

Under a folder named "env", you can create a file for each environment, example: 
env/development.json

```
{
"host" : "testserver",
"username" : "user",
"password" : "*****"
}
```

Then, in your register a task, load that environment file, as follow:

```
grunt.registerTask('deploy', function(env) {
    grunt.config.set('env', grunt.file.readJSON('env/'+env+'.json'));
    ...
    grunt.task.run(['scp:dist']);
});
```

Now, use those variables to configure any task, like this

```
scp: {
  options: {
    host: '<%= secret.host %>',
    username: '<%= secret.username %>',
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync('/repository/server/.ssh/id_rsa_robot'),
    tryKeyboard: true
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      cwd: './dist',
      src: '**/*',
      filter: 'isFile',
       // path on the server
      dest: '/path/to/deploy/project.test'
    }]  
  }
 }
```

Finally, call the grunt task with the environment as parameter

```
grunt deploy:development
```

Comment: correction:

grunt.config.set('secret', grunt.file.readJSON('env/'+env+'.json'));