# Something else besides app.get('env') to detect environment

Tags: node.js, express

Sometimes I don't have access to `app` let's say in my Database Pool singleton and I need a way to detect the environment while instantiating pools and other resources etc, retrieve development or production configs.

I tried to lookup `process` object and `process.env` but couldn't find much.

Wondering if there's another way to detect the environment, I came across passing variables when running `app.js` but it's not possible in the production environment, so any other suggestions please.

or as a last resort, I'll add a variable to process.env object in a cautious manner.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js

Comment: I believe `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE` requires me to set variable to each environment where code runs on, that's what I wanna avoid

Comment: my current workaround is setting `process.app = app` and then accessing it in modules where `app` is not available

Comment: You can simply declare a global variable in that case. Otherwise, take a look at Dependency Injection approach http://nerdventure.io/fount-dependency-injection-for-node-js/

Comment: thanks. used `GLOBAL.env = app.get('env')`