# Node JS Absolute paths using windows % variables treated as relative

Tags: javascript, node.js, filepath, fs

I am using `fs.unlinkSync()` method in a Node.js script, in order to remove a file located in `Appdata` directory.

Best practice of locating the `Appdata` dir is specifying a path using `%appdata%`, so in my code:

```
var filePath = '%appdata%/some/path/file.ext';
fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
```

The problem is an error is returned, indicating bad path, because it's trying to locate something like:

```
C:\my\project\%appdata%\some\path\file.ext
```

Which obviously doesn't exist.

So I'm looking for the best method to resolve `%appdata%` into `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming`.

Hopefully I can do something along the lines of:

```
var filePath = resolveToAbsolutePath('%appdata%/some/path/file.ext');
fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Notes:

1. Nope, the issue is unrelated to using forward slashes instead of backslashes.
2. **This is different than using environment variables**, as I get the paths externally, and I need to be able to resolve % paths as well. I'm interested in generalising the solution, rather than manually replacing paths with environment variable data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read environment variable in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, as I'm not looking to manually replace a known string with a known variable. I'm looking to resolve any path into it's full, absolute version. The question linked is suggesting manually replacing known variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resolve it using a function that will resolve the path:

```
function resolveToAbsolutePath(path) {
    return path.replace(/%([^%]+)%/g, function(_, key) {
        return process.env[key];
    });
}
resolveToAbsolutePath('%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Google\\Chrome\\Application');
```