# How do I deploy a node js app with rethinkdb?

Tags: node.js, deployment, rethinkdb

I've never deployed an app before so I'm completely lost.  If anyone can help or point me to a resource I can use, that would be much appreciated.
If there is other information I need to provide, please let me know.
I would like to get this done in the fastest way possible.

I am using R(ethinkdb)EAN stack.

Comment: For the case you have on your server a similar setup as in your development environment you can use environment variables to tell you app on which environment it's running to select the correct configuration which contains e.g. the rethink credentials http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js

Comment: what should I be using to deploy? I tried heroku but I haven't been able to get it to work