# How to run grunt task based on environment variable?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

For example, I have something like this:

```
  if(ENV === 'production') {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['mkdir', 'copy', 'min']); // production
  } else {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['mkdir', 'copy']); // dev
  }
```

if I do `ENV=development grunt` or `grunt`, I want `dev` task to be executed, and if I do `ENV=production grunt`, i want production task to be executed.

I cannot register two tasks: `default-dev`, `default-prod` and run `grunt default-dev` or `grunt default-prod`.

I have to use ENV variable to specify which task to run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33448470/1838811 you can use this to get `ENV` and use the code you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace you `ENV` with `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Refer [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['mkdir', 'copy', 'min']); // production
} else {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['mkdir', 'copy']); // dev
}
```