# Export GitLab CI variables to json file

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a nodejs repository in gitlab service and I use gitlab CI runner with docker. I need to output some GitLab CI variables (like CI_JOB_ID or CI_COMMIT_TAG) directly to node app. Using gitlab http api is not good for me. I need to store that information to any.json file right after build process. How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [environment variables](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) in your nodejs application should do the trick as explained in this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870450/2078207):

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE
```

All Gitlab CI injected variables should be accessible.