# Can we share the global variables across js files without using require or module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, global-variables

I tried to share my global variable across js files and also in gulp task without using module.exports and require.

Here is the sample code:

File 1:

server.js

```
var server = new Hapi.Server()
  global.configurationManagerObj = 'Dev'
```

File 2:

siteconfig.js

```
console.log("This is global variable from server file",global.configurationManagerObj)
```

File 3:

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('setenv', function(done) {
    console.log("Global variable is shared in gulp task", global.configurationManagerObj);
    done();
});
```

But If I tried to get the variable it shows undefined.

Comment: How can to refer files without require or exports there should be a common reference ti access variables

Comment: You have to require server.js at least once somewhere. Otherwise how node would know about you global variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your can assign variable on global `process` object and can access it anywhere.

this might help [read-environment-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/read-environment-variables-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks Fazal.. it works when I use like this process.env.config = 'dev'
but If I using it in gulp task it shows undefined why?

Answer (score 0):

env variable is only available in Nodejs process .if node is not running u will not have the variable.and u cant get that variable outside the node process also. so better you use require i think
ps: totally personal view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using environment variable to store global variables? `process.env` is build in to nodejs.

Ex. process.env.FOO = "foo"

You'll only be able to access it when the node process is running otherwise it will just show everything as `undefined`.

**PS: Keep in mind that this is an anti pattern. Also, assigning a property on `process.env` will implicitly convert the value to a string.**