# How to access environment variables inside React JS web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, environment-variables

I have an environment variable that I need to access inside my render method. Since its a custom ENV variable, I cannot use (process.env.NODE_ENV). I have [read that React sanitises all process.env access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870450/5898523).

How to access my custom environment variable (CLUSTER_ENV) inside React web app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using webpack, it is possible with **Webpack Define** plugin.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
    ...
    plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
     })
    ]      
    ...
```

and then simply you can use on your javascript file.

```
console.log(NODE_ENV);
```

edit: not alias, define plugin.

Comment: I am using react meteor application, I need to use these env varible in react component,  I am having babel rather than webpack