# Environment variables in Azure WebApp with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have successfully run a Node.js Webapp on Azure, which is connecting to an Azure SQL DB. Everything is working fine when entering the DB details manually into the code.

The issue comes when I try and use the connection details as environment variables.

My Node.js connection looks like this:

```
const config = {
user: `${APPSETTING_user}`,
password: `${APPSETTING_pw}`,
server: `${APPSETTING_host}`,
database: `${APPSETTING_db}`,
options: 
 {
  encrypt: true
 }
};
```

In the Azure Webapp, I have done the following:

- Application Settings > App Settings

Entered the following:

- Key: user, Value: {db user login}
- Key: pw, Value: {my password}
- Key: host, Value: {SQL server address}
- Key: db, Value: {db name>}

*Correct working values in plain text without curly brackets obviously.*

I am getting an error on load that is cannot find db server: `${APPSETTING_host}`

I have been looking through documentation and tutorials, which is limited or out of date on this - however from what I have read apparently I am doing it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE` to read environment variables in Node. So in your case, it would be `process.env.user`, `process.env.pw`, etc...

See [Read environment variables in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/read-environment-variables-in-node-js) for details.