# Conditionally detecting whether a Node server is running inside a Docker Container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have my node.js code where I establish mongodb connections like this: `mongodb://localhost:27017/mycollection`

Now, I put my server in one container and db in another container and I am able to connect to my db from the server like this: `mongodb://mycontainer:27017/mycollection`

I have this connection string configured in my server code/config.

Now, how do I detect whether a person is running the server in a container or not and accordingly take the connection string for the db?

If he is running it in the host machine, I want to use the first connection string with localhost and connect to the db in the host machine and if he connects through a container, I want to use the container link name to connect as mentioned in the second case.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, when I want to accomplish that, I set an `ENV` variable in the Dockerfile like the following:

```
ENV DATABASE_HOST db
```

You can have the full documentation on the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env).

Then, in your Node.js code source, you need to know whether the `DATABASE_HOST` is set or not (I can redirect you to [this Stack Overflow Jayesh's post: Read environment variables in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/read-environment-variables-in-node-js)):

```
var dbHost = 'localhost';

if (process.env.DATABASE_HOST) {
    dbHost = process.env.DATABASE_HOST;
}
```

or in one line:

```
var dbHost = process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost';
```

Then, for MongoDB connection:

```
var mongodbConnection = 'mongodb://' + dbHost + ':27017/mycollection'
```

Now, when you run the container, you must link the container in the `docker run` command with `--link <your mongodb container>:db` (since `db` is the value set in the `ENV` variable).

**But**, you can also use the option `-e DATABASE_HOST=<somthing else>` (again with the `docker run` command) and use a MongoDB container under another name: `-e DATABASE_HOST=anotherOne --link mongo:anotherOne`.

And again, you can use an external MongoDB without linking any container if you want (which is not in another container maybe): `-e DATABASE_HOST=www.mymongo.com`.

EDIT: This solution is maybe better than just identifying if the application is run in a Docker container because with this one your code is usable anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why I did not think of using an ENV for the DB host as well. Will do it this way. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

[is-docker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-docker) is a popular npm packages to accomplish this.

```js
import isDocker from 'is-docker';

if (isDocker()) {
    console.log('Running inside a Docker container');
}
```

The purpose of me using the dependency is perhaps for those who are trying to determine which host to use on their database.

```js
import isDocker from "is-docker";

const host = !!isDocker() ? "host.docker.internal" : env.NODE_DB_HOST;
```

Comment: While this works, one should think about if it is really necessary/worth adding another dependency to a project. Especially if it can be easily solved, without adding a dependency. This is true for any module you think about adding.

Comment: Typically I would agree this package is only 429bytes and very popular.  I made the post just to contribute to the community since there are programmers of all levels. https://npmtrends.com/is-docker

Comment: `Typically I would agree this package is only 429bytes and very popular.` that is not really an argument for using it. The `left-pad` module was also really popular and only a few bytes. Especially for modules that consist only of a few lines of code and just provide some convenient functions, you should think twice if it is really worth adding it to the project.

Comment: The above cited example did not work for me in my environment.  I tried this library and it immediately solved my problem.  It has 20 million downloads a week perhaps it is for the same reason.