# Environment variables are not set in docker container using docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I have a `.env` file like below:

```
# DEV
SALES_DB_HOST=xxx
```

Then I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  web:
    image: xxx
    build: .
    env_file: .env
```

However, the values for the environment variables when accessed in nodejs like `process.env.SALES_DB_HOST` it prints `undefined`.

Output of `docker-compose config` is:

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: xxxxxxxx
    environment:
      SALES_DB_HOST: xxx
    image: xxxxx
version: '3.1'
```

So, it looks like `docker-compose.yml` is formed correctly. But why is `process.env` not getting this value correctly?

EDIT:

I build the docker image with: `docker build -t my_image .`

Comment: Why do you have an extra `process.env` in there? Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4870328/596285) help?

Comment: @BMitch Sorry, it was a typo in the question. I used `process.env.SALES_DB_HOST` in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Can you change command on you container configuration in yml file.
You should try to test your environment to understand - where is a problem. In docker or in your code.

Try something like this:

```
maxantonov : ~/passbolt  .$ cat dc.yml
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    image: alpine:latest
    container_name: db
    hostname: db
    env_file:
      - env/mysql.env
    command: ["printenv"]

maxantonov : ~/passbolt  .$ docker-compose -f dc.yml up
Starting db ... done
Attaching to db
db    | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
db    | HOSTNAME=db
db    | MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
db    | MYSQL_DATABASE=passbolt
db    | MYSQL_USER=passbolt
db    | MYSQL_PASSWORD=P4ssb0lt
db    | HOME=/root
db exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a docker problem. 
Look to your code:

```
process.env.process.env.SALES_DB_HOST
```

It's typo. **process.env.process.env**

You shold use

```
process.env.SALES_DB_HOST
```

Comment: Sorry, the typo was in my question not in the code. I was using `process.env.SALES_DB_HOST` all along.