# Read all shell environment variables in Node.js

Tags: node.js, shell

I want to read all shell environment variables in Node.js.There is [a similar 
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/read-environment-variables-in-node-js).But I find `process.env` cannot read customize variables.

[image]
[image]

as you can see ,process.env does not include some variables such as `JAVA_HOME` `NVM_DIR`.

How to get them?

I can see two ways:

- read `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` then calculate what variables user set .
- or to call shell command `env` in nodejs.

But there are too  complex. Is there a simple way to get them?

Comment: is "learngo" part of your prompt or is it a command?

Comment: looks like `learngo` sets additional variables for itself... ?

Comment: @glennjackman learngo is just a folder name