# How do I fix johnny 5 installation error?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, johnny-five

I'm trying to install johnny-five on windows7 64 bit. I have an earlier version of Node  (v.13.14.0-64) installed and I use Visual Studio Code as my code editor.

Regarding the first part of the error, `prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=13.14.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)`. I simply don't know what this means even after reading forums about this error.

I have Python installed and the error says it can't find it. I went to [this](http://%20https://newbedev.com/python-c-path-to-python-exe-code-example) website trying to fix the error but still wasn't able to find a solution.

```
> @serialport/bindings@8.0.8 install C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\NODE\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
> prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=13.14.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\NODE\node_modules\@serialport\bindings>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\NODE\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
gyp ERR! node -v v13.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\NODE\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\NODE\package.json'
npm WARN NODE No description
npm WARN NODE No repository field.
npm WARN NODE No README data
npm WARN NODE No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @serialport/bindings@8.0.8 (node_modules\@serialport\bindings):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @serialport/bindings@8.0.8 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ johnny-five@2.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 101 packages in 8.473s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you run python from the windows console? Could be you just have to add its location to the PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I edited the Path variable in sysdm.cpl and directed it to Python. 

I found the file location by typing:
`>>>import sys  

>>> print(sys.executable)`  
on the Python cmd line.

Then I tried reinstalling johnny-five using the command:

`npm install johnny-five`

However the error message is the same as my original post.

I attempted running python from Terminal with the command: `python` and it gives me this error: `‘python’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What would you suggest next?

Comment: And what about sys variables in js?

Comment: The only thing I knew about sys variables is PATH for Python.

I found env config instructions on Medium but they are too advanced for me.

Do you have beginner instructions on setting up my environment?

Also, there are some threads on Github with similar errors as the one on the original post. There Is an issue with the serial port that I don’t completely understand. There could be a conflict between the version of serial-port and the operating system (Windows 7). I run Windows 7, so I'm considering upgrading to Windows 10 if it will help.

What would you recommend at this point?

Comment: First you should check your env in js, just like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/read-environment-variables-in-node-js.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi The link you sent me helped me out a lot! Thanks! I had to post a new thread here because a moderator directed me to create a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105560/how-to-fix-firmware-error-running-js-file

Comment: New link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70193360/how-do-i-solve-javascript-execution-error-in-johnny-five