# Use node.js commandline argument as environment variable

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

I call my node.js application with

```
node index.js a=5
```

I want to use the value '5' directly as an environment variable in my code like

```
const myNumber = process.env.a
```

(like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/read-environment-variables-in-node-js)).

If I try the above, 'MyNumber' is undefinded on runtime.

## Solution

- Linux:

```
a=5 node index.js
```

- Windows (Powershell):

```
    $env:a="5";node index.js
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing `node index.js a=5`, `a=5` is an argument for node, as index.js is.

If you want to pass an environment variable, you must specify it before node command : `a=5 node index.js`.

The node `process.env` is populated with your bash environment variables.

Comment: Thank you! That works. BTW: I'm on Windows. So the environment variable can be used with `$env:a="5"` in a previous command (not in the same line).

Answer (score 1):

`a=5` is an argument to your script not an environment variable. to access the argument in the script use `process.argv`

https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/

Answer (score 1):

Right now, when you run the following command, it is setting an argument for Node.js (your `index.js` file).

```
$ node index.js a=5
```

You can access this using the code below. It will simply return the value the first value passed in.

```js
// node index.js a=5
process.argv[2]
```

You need to get the 2<sup>nd</sup> index, as the first 2 are just command line ones.

---

If you want to pass an environment variable, you need to set it before running the command, as so.

```
$ a=5 node index.js
```

You can then access it with `process.env`, as you have already specified.