# How do I load a password from a config file in puppeteer?

Tags: passwords, puppeteer

I have a password. I don't want to commit it to the repo. I am writing tests with puppeteer. The logical thing to do would be to save the password in a file somewhere, git-ignore the file, then load it in puppeteer. But I'm not sure how to do that. Suggestions?

This is what I am trying. It doesn't work, yet:

file loadPassword.js:

```
import { config } from "dotenv";  // This appears in lightweight type in VS code, implying that VS code thinks the line is not doing anything.

console.log('getting password');
let pass = process.env.PASSWORD;
console.log('the actual password has been loaded into the variable "pass".');
console.log('the password is ', pass);
let foo = process.env['PASSWORD'];
console.log(foo);
// but when I run, both pass and foo print out as undefined.
```

file .env:

```
{
    PASSWORD: 'secret'
}
```

file package.json:

```
{
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "puppeteer": "^19.8.3"
    }
}
```

To run, in terminal:

```
node loadPassword
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read environment variables in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/read-environment-variables-in-node-js)

Comment: This appears to be unrelated to Puppeteer. The normal node approach is to create a `.env` file, add it to your `.gitignore`, put your secret in as `PASSWORD=secret`, then use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load it: `require("dotenv").config()`, then access it with `process.env.PASSWORD`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49611972/6243352).

Comment: Not yet, require is throwing an exception. I tried 'import {config} from "dotenv";' instead, but the password is coming through as undefined, even though it is in the '.env' file. Trying to tweak it so it behaves.

Comment: Could you update your post to show your code, dotenv version (or package.json), file contents and directory tree? I'll try to reproduce the problem locally. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This works, but I'd still be interested in a better solution:

file .gitignore:

```
password.js
```

file password.js:

```
export function getPassword() {
    return 'secret';
}
```

file password.js.template:

```
export function getPassword() {
    return 'copy and paste this file to a file password.js, then put your actual password here in the copy.';
}
```

file loadPassword.js:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { getPassword } from './password.js';

(async () => {
    console.log('getting password');
    let pass = getPassword();
    console.log('the actual password has been loaded into the variable "pass".')
})();
```

To run, in terminal:

```
node loadPassword
```

Comment: I'll happily delete this myself if I can get the .env method to actually work.