# How to Parameterise a boolean value in process.env

Tags: node.js, typescript, playwright

I have a playwright script that requires to have boolean value for the headless option. I would like to pass this as a parameter in process.env. The pipeline build will accept headless version but when someone wants to run it locally, it would be best to run it in the headed version. Hence it would be convenient to parameterize it.

```
  import test, { Browser, chromium, expect, Page } from '@playwright/test'



  async function authSetup() {
    
    const browser: Browser = await chromium.launch({headless: process.env.headless})
    const context = await browser.newContext()
    const page: Page = await context.newPage()
```

This results in an error:

```
Error: browserType.launch: headless: expected boolean, got string
```

Comment: See also [avoid booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52199710/6243352)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare its value.

```js
{ headless: process.env.headless === "true" }
```

Comment: Just curious, why did you choose in this context '===' over  '==' . Any added benefits?

Answer (score 1):

Values in [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processenv) are always strings, not just when they come from outside the process (from the actual environment) but also if you set a value yourself:

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string.

Since the value will always be either `undefined` or a string (and not a boolean), you could add an explicit check for a certain value (`process.env.headless === 'true'`) or you could create a list of "truthy" or "falsy" values.

You could also use a package like [yn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yn) which includes such a list already:

> The following case-insensitive values are recognized:
>
> ```
> 'y', 'yes', 'true', true, '1', 1, 'n', 'no', 
> 'false', false, '0', 0, 'on', 'off'
> ```

Which would look like this:

```
chromium.launch({headless: yn(process.env.headless, {default: false})})
```

This will only run the process headless if the value is "true", "1", etc.
If no value is defined (or explicitly set to a false value) it will not run headless.